# asp.net label in GridView returns "" after setting its text from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, text, label

I was able to change and retrieve label text from jQuery, but when I try to get it from server side it always returns empty text.

here is the label code in the grid-view

```
 <asp:Label ID="imglabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and here how I change the text from the JQuery

```
 $('<%="#"+GridView1.ClientID %>').find('span[id*="imglabel"]').text("minus");
```

but when I try to get the text from server side as shown in the next code:

```
 int GVcount = 0;
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
 {
     Label hf = (Label)GridView1.Rows[GVcount].FindControl("imglabel");  
     string test = hf.Text;
 }
```

test variable is always return "" instead of "minus".

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Add hidden field also and store value in hidden field and access it from code behind.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. It works perfectly with hidden field :)